# How to pass a char pointer by address to be accepted to char**?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, pass-by-reference

I have a struct, known as Shader, which holds the following information:

```
struct Shader {
    enum ValueType{ VT_Attribute, VT_Uniform, VT_Varying };
    GLuint Memory;
    GLenum Type;
    char* Source;
    char* Name;
    std::map< Shader::ValueType, float* > Values;
};
```

Yet, if I do something like:

`glShaderSource( shaderMem, 1, &shader.Source, NULL );`

I get the following error:

`error: invalid conversion from 'char* const*' to 'const char**'`

Why is this happening?

Comment: Sscce.org.  Are you sure it's complaining about the third argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because `shader` is `const` at that point. Assuming `glShaderSource` won't attempt to write the contents of its 3rd argument, then you can `const_cast` the `const` away:

```
glShaderSource( shaderMem, 1, const_cast< char** >( &shader.Source ), NULL );
```

Comment: I would accept your answer, but I have 8 minutes left. You get the gold star, thanks :)

Comment: @blissfreak, think you forgot to award it :)

Comment: Better late than never!